# Function-type Variable declaration - typo on official golang document page

Tags: go

At golang.org blog [here](https://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax#TOC_3) we have the syntax to declare a function-type variable

```
f func(func(int,int) int, int) func(int, int) int
```

and I don't understand since it should be as below i.e. without the last 'int'

```
f func(func(int,int) int, int) func(int, int)
```

I'm a Go newbie and I may misunderstand something here.
So is that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct.

This:

```
f func(func(int,int) int, int) func(int, int) int
```

is a function `f` which takes 2 params, first is of type `func(int,int) int`, second is an `int`, and returns a function that has 2 `int` params and an `int` return type.

This:

```
f func(func(int,int) int, int) func(int, int)
```

is mostly the same, but the return function type only has 2 `int` params, and does not return anything.

So there is no typo in the doc.

Comment: Thanks! So I guess it's clearer to be ```f func(func(int,int) int, int) (func(int, int) int)``` isn't it?

Comment: @NamGVU That's the point of the _left-to-right_ style syntax of Go: it's unambiguous without the extra parenthesis. I could read it without having to think about multiple valid interpretations. You'll get used to it.

Comment: I guess so. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a typo.

`f func(func(int,int) int, int) func(int, int) int`

It means the function returns a function that has 2 int params and an int return type.